# Google maps container rounding does not work on iPad, iPhone, Android

Tags: jquery, google-maps, css, rounded-corners

I searched around here and I've done many tests and I can not get my google maps to display in a round container.

So far it works for these browsers:
firefox
internet explorer 10
Opera
Safari (PC)

None of my solutions work on the iPad, iPhone or Android devices.

Has anyone had the same problem?

Here's my example: http://mbcapps.es/desarrollo/contacto.html

Thank you all.

Javier

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your site on my Droid and the Google Map container was round. I also look at it at  http://ipadpeek.com/ and the container was reading your border-radius style on iPad and iPhone5.